# Replaykit The Mic is not recording audio even if the mic is enabled

Tags: swift, replaykit

I have used `ReplayKit` for recording Screen of my App.Also I have used `microphoneEnabled = true`. The very first time the device asks for permission for recording with Microphone. It records the screen with audio also.

But the next time I try to record the screen , there is no sound in the file.

I have attached two methods one for **starting the recording** and other for **stopping the recording**.

```
func startRecording(withFileName fileName: String, recordingHandler:@escaping (Error?)-> Void)
    {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
        {

            let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: ReplayFileUtil.filePath(fileName))
            assetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: fileURL, fileType:
                AVFileType.mp4)
            currentVideoURL = fileURL
            let videoOutputSettings: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264,
                AVVideoWidthKey : floor(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width*1.2/16)*16,
                AVVideoHeightKey : floor(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height*1.2/16)*16
            ];

            videoInput  = AVAssetWriterInput (mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: videoOutputSettings)


            let audioSettings = [
                AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
                AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
                //AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue
                //AVEncoderBitRateKey: 192000
                ] as [String : Any]


            audioAssetWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio, outputSettings: audioSettings)

            audioAssetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

            videoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
            assetWriter.add(videoInput)
            assetWriter.add(audioAssetWriterInput)

            guard recorder.isAvailable else {
                print("Recording is not available at this time.")
                return
            }
            self.recorder.isMicrophoneEnabled = true


            recorder.startCapture(handler: { (sample, bufferType, error) in
//                print(sample,bufferType,error)

                recordingHandler(error)

                if CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sample)
                {
                    if self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.unknown
                    {
                        self.assetWriter.startWriting()
                        self.assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sample))
                    }
                    if self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.failed {
                        print("Error occured, status = \(self.assetWriter.status.rawValue), \(self.assetWriter.error!.localizedDescription) \(String(describing: self.assetWriter.error))")
                        return
                    }

                    if (bufferType == .video)
                    {
                        if self.videoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData
                        {
                            self.videoInput.append(sample)
                        }
                    }else if (bufferType == .audioMic)
                    {
                        if self.audioAssetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData
                        {
                            self.audioAssetWriterInput.append(sample)
                        }
                    }

                }

  func stopRecording(handler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
    {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
        {
            recorder.stopCapture
            {    (error) in
                    handler(error)
                    self.assetWriter.finishWriting
                {
                    print(ReplayFileUtil.fetchAllReplays())
                    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.currentVideoURL!.relativePath, self, nil, nil)
                }
            }
```

Comment: 1. remove the application 
2. Restart your device
3. install application and check,
In my case, it will work for the very first time once I remove application from the stack, Microphone recording during screen capture stop working.

Comment: @Jasmeet Singh Did it work?

Comment: Hello @Jasmeet, Did you find any solution because I am facing same issue?